# Using wget to download a list of files using -i option

Tags: wget

I am trying to download a list of files using wget using this file here: http://webdatacommons.org/downloads/2012-08/nquads/files.list

As described here: http://webdatacommons.org/2012-08/stats/how_to_get_the_data.html#toc0

But I get following message:

> `rbhagdev@rbhagdev-linux:~/RDF$ wget -i files.list`
>   --2013-05-01 11:49:44--  http://webdatacommons.org/downloads/2012-08/nquads/html-mf-geo-00000.nq.sort.gz%0Dhttp://webdatacommons.org/downloads/2012-08/nquads/html-mf-geo-00001.nq.sort.gz%0Dhttp://webdatacommons.org/downloads/2012-08/nquads/html-mf-geo-00002.nq.sort.gz%0Dhttp://webdatacommons.org/downloads/2012-08/nquads/html-mf-geo-00003.nq.sort.gz%0Dhttp://webdatacommons.org/downloads/2012-08/nquads/html-mf-geo-00004.nq.sort.gz%0Dhttp://webdatacommons.org/downloads/2012-08/nquads/html-mf-geo-00005.nq.sort.gz%0Dhttp://webdatacommons.org/downloads/2012-08/nquads/html-mf-geo-00006.nq.sort.gz%0Dhttp://webdatacommons.org/downloads/2012-08/nquads/html-mf-hcalendar-00000.nq.sort.gz
>   Resolving webdatacommons.org (webdatacommons.org)... 129.13.253.75
>   Connecting to webdatacommons.org
>   (webdatacommons.org)|129.13.253.75|:80... connected. HTTP request
>   sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden 2013-05-01 11:49:44 ERROR
>   403: Forbidden.

If I only use a single line in that file, it works.  Which suggests that this maybe something to do with the newline character?  I am on Ubuntu.  Can someone please suggest why wget is behaving this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must substitute the end of line character of the file. You can use this command to do it

```
sed -e 's/\r/\n/g' files.list > files.list.new
wget -i files.list.new
```

Comment: Argh, right so it was just the line separator.  Thanks!